# remove both lines if the second line is shorter than specific length

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file that looks like:

```
>NB501365:508:HJF2HBGXF:1:12102:14401:14957 1:N:0:CTTGTA
GAATCTTCATGTGAGGAACAGAATTCAGC
>NB501365:508:HJF2HBGXF:1:12102:17671:14957 1:N:0:CTTGTA
ATCGTG
>NB501365:508:HJF2HBGXF:1:12102:14401:14957 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CCCCCCCCCGGGGCTCGGGGGGGCTGG
```

each bucket starts with `>` sign. I want to keep the buckets of my file if the length of the second line of each bucket is `>=` than 15.

So my ideal output should be:

```
>NB501365:508:HJF2HBGXF:1:12102:14401:14957 1:N:0:CTTGTA
GAATCTTCATGTGAGGAACAGAATTCAGC
>NB501365:508:HJF2HBGXF:1:12102:14401:14957 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CCCCCCCCCGGGGCTCGGGGGGGCTGG
```

I looked at different posts in Stackoverflow but still not able to make it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested it in https://ideone.com/MN9K22

```
awk '/^>/{val=$0;next} length($0)>=15{print val ORS $0;val=""}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                  ##Starting awk program from here.
/^>/{                  ##Checking condition if line starts from > then do following.
  val=$0               ##Creating val which has current line.
  next                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
length($0)>=15{        ##Checking condition if current line length is greater than 15 then do following.
  print val ORS $0     ##Printing val ORS(new line) and current line here.
  val=""               ##Nullify val here.
}
' Input_file           ##Mentioning Input_file name here
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^>/{N;/\n.{15}/!d}' file
```

If line begins with `>` append the next and then if the regexp which matches 15 or more characters in the appended line fails, delete the pair.

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- all data lines come in pairs
- the first line of a pair starts with `>` in the first column

Sample data:

```
$ cat stuff.dat
>NB501365:508:HJF2HBGXF:1:12102:14401:14957 1:N:0:CTTGTA
GAATCTTCATGTGAGGAACAGAATTCAGC
>NB501365:508:HJF2HBGXF:1:12102:17671:14957 1:N:0:CTTGTA
ATCGTG
>NB501365:508:HJF2HBGXF:1:12102:14401:14957 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CCCCCCCCCGGGGCTCGGGGGGGCTGG
```

One `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '
/^>/ { line1=$0
       getline
       line2=$0
       if (length(line2) >= 15)
          { printf "%s\n%s\n", line1, line2}
     }
' stuff.dat
>NB501365:508:HJF2HBGXF:1:12102:14401:14957 1:N:0:CTTGTA
GAATCTTCATGTGAGGAACAGAATTCAGC
>NB501365:508:HJF2HBGXF:1:12102:14401:14957 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CCCCCCCCCGGGGCTCGGGGGGGCTGG
```